# Example of a finite solvable group with non-solvable automorphism group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

If $G$ is a finite group with $\text{Aut}(G)$ solvable, then $G$ itself must be solvable. Because then $G/Z(G)$ is solvable and obviously $Z(G)$ is solvable, and hence $G$ itself must be solvable. But what about the converse? Can $G$ be solvable and $\text{Aut}(G)$ be non-solvable?

Comment: Take a finite abelian group $G=Z_p^n$, $p$ is prime. Then $Aut(G)$ equals $GL(n, Z_p)$ which is not solvable with few exceptions.

Comment: I think one can obtain many of them, by taking the direct product of any finite solvable group and an abelian group, as in that case, modulo a nilpotent subgroup the central automorphism group is a direct product of full linear groups.

Comment: Studiosus and Yassine: thanks!!! - I was thinking in a totally different direction, apparently too late yesterday night, my brain was not at full speed.

Comment: @studiosus: Could you post that as an answer? :) I shall upvote it! [We](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/12092037#12092037) are trying to get this question off the "unanswered" question list.

Comment: @Prism: I just did.

Comment: A little note... we say a group has the *Schreier property* if $\operatorname{Out}(G)\cong \operatorname{Aut}(G)/\operatorname{Inn}(G)$ is solvable.  As you noticed, $\operatorname{Inn}(G)$ is always solvable when $G$ is solvable, so the solvable groups with solvable automorphism groups are precisely those with the Schreier property.

Answer (score 7):

Take a finite abelian group $G=Z^n_p$, $p$ is prime. Then $Aut(G)$ equals $GL(n, Z_p)$ which is not solvable with few exceptions. Here $Z_p$ is the cyclic group of order $p$.

Comment: Nice solution :)